# Can two network adapters work in different IP protocols simultaneously？

Tags: windows-7, macos, networking, network-protocols

My laptop has two network adapters, one is wireless and connected wirelessly to a wireless router, another one is wired and connected to a network supported IPv6 with cable.
The question is , can I assign different network request to different network adapter? For instance, assign IPv4 request to wireless adapter and assign IPv6 request to wired adapter? Or is there a software can handle this?
Any help is appreciated! 
FYI, the OS in this topic is either Windows 7 or Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

When you go into the network adaptor properties in Windows 7 you can tick and untick the protocols that you wish to use with that adaptor, so just untick IPv6 on one of them and untick IPv4 on the other.

On a Mac, you can go into Network Preferences, click an interface on the left and then click on Advanced and then TCP/IP. You can then selectively enable both IPv4 and IPv6 on the interface that you have selected.

Comment: I tried in Windows 7 but it seems not working. When I untick the IPv4 protocol in wired adapter(IPv6 remain ticked) and I just can't access any IPv6 website or downloading IPv6 resources via BT :(

Comment: Do you have valid IPv6 DNS? Does it resolve and can you then ping external IPv6 hosts?

Comment: I use IPCONFIG instruction and do see IPv6 address, default gateway and some other information but when I ping external IPv6 hosts(ipv6.google.com), there is no response. I don't know if there is a specific IPv6 DNS because normally when I use the cable to connect to IPv6 it will automatically assign IP address and DNS settings to me, btw, it's university's network.